# How to activate infopath services for sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, feature-activation

I want to work with infopath services available in sharepoint 2010 environment.
My machine has inforpath designer and filler 2010. When I went to `site collection features --> Sharepoint server enterprise site collection features` and try to activate it, giving following error.

> NOSCOPE  The feature you are trying to activate is dependent on
>   another feature c88c4ff1-dbf5-4649-ad9f-c6c426ebcbf5 contained in the
>   solution 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 which is not installed.

What it means? Do I need anything to activate before. Please give me suggestions!!

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you must activate InfoPath Forms Services from Central Administration. See [this Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262263%28office.14%29.aspx) for specifics. I will quote what appears to be the relevant section. As I do not personally have access to Central Admin on my production server I cannot validate this answer:

1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a
   member of the Farm Administrators SharePoint group.
2. On the Quick Launch of the Central Administration Web site, click General Application Settings.
3. On the General Application Settings page, in the InfoPath Forms Services section, click Configure InfoPath Form Services

Answer (score 0):

Check if `State Service` is enabled. If not, run the Configuration Wizard in Central Admin and enable it.
For more details check out the the following link:

http://www.appvity.com/blogs/post/2013/06/16/How-to-configure-and-publish-InfoPath-to-SharePoint-2013.aspx

PS: For SharePoint 2013 ( But its no different than SharePoint 2010)